# How to target Notebooks and Desktops on Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap's largest grid is 1200px wide, but there are several scenarios where I have to tweak CSS for two of the most common resolutions worldwide, 1366x768 and 1920x1080.

What is the correct way of targeting Notebooks (> 1200 < 1400) and actual Desktops (> 1400) in Bootstrap 4?

Comment: one option is to media queries , for devices >=1200, as per documentation says to .col-xl-(extra large)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/GxLVyp

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 <!-- content here -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1400px){ 
  .container{
    max-width: 1168px;
    background-color:olive;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1401px) { 
  .container{
    max-width: 1368px;
    background-color:teal;
  }
}
```

Edit the max-width and other styles for these 2 new media queries as needed.

The above should work with [Bootstrap 4 auto layout columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) as well , here's an example: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/VXOZVW

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but the ideal would be col-notebook-6, col-desktop-6, etc. The only way seem to build a custom grid, right.

Comment: @LucasBustamante, I guess you could create a custom grid, or easier still, go with the native Bootstrap 4 support for auto column layout. Please see my edit above.